# Updating nested objects firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

From the Firebase note:

Given a single key path like `alanisawesome`, `updateChildren()` only updates data at the first child level, and any data passed in beyond the first child level is a treated as a `setValue()` operation. Multi-path behavior allows longer paths (like `alanisawesome/nickname`) to be used without overwriting data. This is why the first example differs from the second example.

I am trying to use a single function `createOrUpdateData(object)` in my code. In case of update, it updates first level children properly, but if I have nested object passed, then it deletes all other properties of that nested object.

Here's the code:

```
function saveUserDetails(email,object){
        var hashedEmail = Utilities.getHashCode(email);
        var userRef = ref.child(hashedEmail);
        return $q(function(resolve,reject){
            return userRef.update(object, function(error){
                if(error){
                    reject(error);
                }else{
                    resolve("Updated successfully!");
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

So if I pass:

```
{
   name: 'Rohan Dalvi', 
   externalLinks: { 
      website: 'mywebsite'
   }
}
```

Then it will delete other properties inside externalLinks object. Is there a cleaner and simpler way of avoiding this?

In short, how do I make sure nested objects are only updated and that data is not deleted.

Comment: Hi @DavidEast , thanks it works! Although I haven't tried to update an array inside a nested object.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use **multi-path updates**.

```
var userRef = ref.child(hashedEmail);
var updateObject = {
   name: 'Rohan Dalvi', 
   "externalLinks/website": 'mywebsite'
};
userRef.update(updateObject);
```

By using the `"externalLinks/website"` syntax in the object literal it will treat the nested path as an update and not a set for the nested object. **This keeps nested data from being deleted.**

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks!

Comment: How can we do this with dynamic object names?

Comment: @OliverDixon With ES6 you can use computed property names, like this:
```js
   const dynamicProperty = 'foo';
   const updateObject = {
      name: 'Rohan Dalvi', 
      [dynamicProperty]: 'mywebsite'
   };
``` 
You can also combine a static string with a dynamic part like this:
```js
    const updateObject = {
      name: 'Rohan Dalvi', 
      [`externalLinks/${dynamicProperty}`]: 'mywebsite'
   };
```

I hope that helps! Sorry for the formatting, I realized that stack overflow comments are not the best place to post code.

Comment: I get the following error using this method:
FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.update() called with invalid data. Invalid field path (externalLinks/website). Paths must not contain '~', '*', '/', '[', or ']'
I update the following way: this.db.collection('members').doc(uid).update(changes);

Answer (score 16):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49150917/update-fields-in-nested-objects-in-firestore-documents) provides a more recent solution that works with cloud firestore.

Rather than using "/", one may use "." instead:

```js
var userRef = ref.child(hashedEmail);
var updateObject = {
   name: 'Rohan Dalvi', 
   "externalLinks.website": 'mywebsite'
};
userRef.update(updateObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

To update nested `object`/`map`/`dictionary` in firebase database, you can use `Firestore.Encoder` to `class`/`struct` that is `Codable`.

Here is a Swift code example:

Models:

```
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

// UserDetails Model
class UserDetailsModel: Codable {
   let name: String, 
   externalLinks: ExternalLinkModel
}    

// UserDetails Model
class ExternalLinkModel: Codable {
   let website: String
}
```

Calling Firebase:

```
    import FirebaseFirestore
    import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

    let firestoreEncoder = Firestore.Encoder()

    let fields: [String: Any] = [
        // using firestore encoder to convert object to firebase map
        "externalLinks": try! firestoreEncoder.encode(externalLinkModel)
    ]

    db.collection(path)
        .document(userId)
        .updateData(fields, completion: { error in
             ...
    })
```