# Update fields in nested objects in firestore documents?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a data structure like:

[image]

I want to edit the value of "test" key in "first" object. I followed the document on https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

But it did not work for me.

The nodejs code:

```
var setAda = dbFirestore.collection('users').doc('alovelace').update({
        first : {
            test: "12345"
            }
});
```

The result in firestore:
[image]

The "test2" key was gone. However, I only want to update the value of "test" and keep the "test2".

Any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

According to the link you provided, it says this:

> If your document contains nested objects, you can use "dot notation" to reference nested fields within the document when you call update():

Therefore you need to use `dot notation` to be able to update only one field without overwriting, so like this:

```
var setAda = dbFirestore.collection('users').doc('alovelace').update({
    "first.test": "12345"
});
```

then you will have:

```
 first
  test: "12345"
  test2: "abcd"
```

Comment: It is not clear from the documentation that ther is a difference in behavior when using the second type signature of `DocumentReference.update`, which results in a hard write: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.html#value:any

Comment: If I wanted to delete the `test.first` entry of the `test` map, would I need to perform a `get()` operation, delete it manually and then update the whole `first` map? Or is there a similar operation to delete nested fields in maps? @peter

Comment: @ppicom you need to do something like this `update({"first.test" :firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()});`

Comment: This is not working with .set({...}, {merge: true) for some reason.

Comment: have u tried the one below https://stackoverflow.com/a/57217966/7015400 @rendom?

Answer (score 33):

Peter's solution's great, but it's not works with dynamic key. Following code can works with it:

```js
var nestedkey = 'test';
var setAda = dbFirestore.collection('users').doc('alovelace').update({
    [`first.${nestedkey}`]: "12345"
});
```

Comment: This is essentially the same as Peter's solution, except it uses template string...

Comment: Great thanks. I tried ${nestedKey} but it didnt worked until I cower it with [].

Comment: Tried to edit out the unnecessary "This code is far better" part and it erred with 'edit queue is full'

Answer (score 12):

If you don't want an exception that occur if 'first' field doesn't exist, try using `set` with `{merge: true}` option instead of `update`.

```
var setAda = dbFirestore.collection('users').doc('alovelace').set({
        first : {
            test: "12345"
        }
}, {merge: true});
```

**Edit:**

Thanks to @Shane Walker, the latest version(9.8.1) of Firestore has been changed so that `update` works the same as `set` with `{merge: true}` option.

[Firebase JavaScript SDK Release Notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js)

Comment: This method also works, but no exception is thrown if the field doesn't exist in the object, it's just added.

Answer (score 9):

In case somebody is using **TypeScript** (like in Cloud functions for example) here is the code to update nested fields with dot notation.

```
var setAda = dbFirestore.collection('users').doc('alovelace').update({
    `first.${variableIfNedded}.test`: "12345"
});
```

Comment: @Vino make sure you are using TypeScript. What is exactly the code you are using?

Comment: When I attempt this approach like `saveData[\`picks.${matchId}.points\`] = pickValue;` where saveData is the Map that I end up writing into firebase. I get a new property created with the name "picks.94904.points" instead of writing into the map. I'm new to typescript so I'm assuming a syntax error. Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: @Chamanhm, you are over complicating your code. Try to make it simpler. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:
Does it work like that?

```
var setAda = dbFirestore.collection('users').doc('alovelace').update({
        "first.test" : "12345"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who need something more generic and recursive, here is a function that updates a Foo Firestore document non destructively with a typescript Partial :

```
private objectToDotNotation(obj: Partial<Foo>, parent = [], keyValue = {}) {
    for (let key in obj) {
        let keyPath = [...parent, key];
        if (obj[key]!== null && typeof obj[key] === 'object')
            Object.assign(keyValue, this.objectToDotNotation(obj[key], keyPath, keyValue));
        else
            keyValue[keyPath.join('.')] = obj[key];
    }
    return keyValue;
}

public update(foo: Partial<Foo>) {
    dbFirestore.collection('foos').doc('fooId').update(
        this.objectToDotNotation(foo)
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `set` function and passing `merge: true` in options to update deeply nested fields without overwriting other fields.

```js
const firstore = firebase.firestore()
const ref = firestore.doc('users/alovelace').set({
  first : {
    test: "12345"
  }
}, { merge: true })
```

With this method, you can update a field even if it's buried 20 levels deep.

Answer (score 0):

**For Swift 4**

```
let dictionary:[String:Any] = ["first.test" : "12345"]
let plansDocumentReference = Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document("alovelace")              
plansDocumentReference.updateData(dictionary) { err in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error updating document: \(err)")

                }}
```

You can update multiple fields by adding records to the dictionary as well as build variable based sub-keys by replacing the fixed text in the dictionary with string variable.

This technique also works to replace entire single key sub-blocks in the document by using a dictionary as the value for any key

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a version in typescript without the extra params, having type completion in mind...  Ended up with the following:

[TS Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABHARgKwKbQCpwCJxQByhAhrAgBSpoBcipYAngJT2NOIDeAUIv4j4CAThighhSAPLosUAHQBrDEwDO1dC3miAJiAgZKiSjrAy0AGkTLWiALwA+bkIECICVVEQA3UgBsQDHtkdABtGwBdAG4XV0E4gRhgY18AoIBCOztEMBA-P0QAMkLEKCYABww4ZNTA+yzEAHIaOUaWbgSE2M7EdzBPXoALGD8dc2CWnHxCEihyeDBKWowWGJ7Xbs7zOSUVdQhh0fMtYDhhAFFSA6MDkZ0AaRV7J151ztNx7K55H4-0K1CAAMACRcGwAX3koNuo0eTHBgIi9BhYzCKLhEUQ4LWbyxq02-HBiAwflUQS4uPiuL+aGC31+Zn+iHCKiRPn8dWxBKxPG5onEkkQNJxhKsXHB+PBvL6AxgYFOqjpsWAMGEniIpAAthh6I0AGK6RoWWJ+UjqrU6pp6s6wMBG3muPpzaAASXlcHor065UGCEtjQATEGALQARgDAGZQ-aeuU4J5-ABBHQ6USqVSe7muTyiDDJ1MYdO6oOITWkOWITwx3EQGBlXVEDAAd0QAE0zopq28E1B-URW131gAvGDlADCcB0loALJHZ9ypa5wcbYhhNeUygAFYRwcr0XL5HhcmVwPwYeRzFBnyhyhX4ngyrymN0KiayKYEYhkCiLW-x+8Ph4p7npe17Pu6qgsEAA)

```
function objectToDotNotation(obj: any): any {

    return Object.keys(obj).reduce( (dnObj, key) => {
        const value = obj[key];

        if (value !== null && typeof value === 'object') {            
            const childObj = objectToDotNotation(value);

            Object.keys(childObj).forEach( childKey => {
                dnObj = {...dnObj, [`${key}.${childKey}`]: childObj[childKey] };
            });
        } else {            
            dnObj = {...dnObj, [key]: value };
        }

        return dnObj;
    }, {});
}
```