# key value a floating point type when update the map type

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to make the key value a floating point type when overwriting the map type in firestore with flutter/dart.

Possible with ".set" but not with ".update"
How is it possible?

```
current output value(.update)
{"40"
 {"0":{"aaa" : "aaa", "bbb" : "bbb"}},
 {"5":{"ccc" : "ccc", "ddd" : "ddd"}}
}

Ideal output value(.set)
{"40.0":{"aaa" : "aaa", "bbb" : "bbb"},
{"40.5":{"ccc" : "ccc", "ddd" : "ddd"}
}
```

Below is the corresponding code.

```
final testRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("test").doc("test");
await testRef.update(
      {
        "40.0": {"aaa" : "aaa", "bbb" : "bbb"},
        "40.5" : {"ccc" : "ccc", "ddd" : "ddd"},
      }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

In an `update` call a `.` is used as a field separator, so your code updates the `0` and `5` subfields of the top-level `40` field.

If you want to address a top-level field with a `.` in its name, you can create a `FieldPath` object to refer to it:

```
testRef.update({
  FieldPath(["40.0"]): {"aaa" : "aaa", "bbb" : "bbb"},
  FieldPath(["40.5"]): {"ccc" : "ccc", "ddd" : "ddd"},
});
```

Also see:

- [Firestore - How to update a field that contains period(.) in it's key from Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49643235/firestore-how-to-update-a-field-that-contains-period-in-its-key-from-andro) (although this is for Android, the approach is similar)
- [String being converted to map when setting data on firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61593648/string-being-converted-to-map-when-setting-data-on-firestore)