# Javascript store (firebase)firestore data always overwrite the first part data

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am use the html, javascript and firebase to create the message board , and store the data.
But I need to save the data , if the userID(ex:0001) is the same, it is can create the object of

```
{name:"userName",
 date:"2019",
description:"the message content"};
```

[image]

Now if have new data, I don't overwrite the

```
{name:"userName",
 date:"2019",
description:"the message content"};
```

data.

If I have other message, and the userId is the same(0001), the object is

```
 {name:"userName2(displayname)",
     date:"2019",
    description:"the other message content"};
```

data.

I don't want to overwrite the first part data, I need insert new data on the column.

is it possible repeat other object in the column?

my javascript code below, the code always overwrite first part data.:(

```
 firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    var db = firebase.firestore();

  var userData2 = {name:"userName2(displayname)",
          date:"2019",
          description:"the other message content"};

 db.collection("suggest").doc("0001").set(userData2,{merge: false})
          .then(function() {
              console.log("Successfully written!");
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
              console.error("Error writing: ", error);
          });
```

thank you very much.

Comment: The data can't like the array , repeat other the same object?

Comment: sorry, what is pushid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
db.collection("suggest").doc("0001").set(userData2,{merge: false})
          .then(function() {
              console.log("Successfully written!");
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
              console.error("Error writing: ", error);
          });
```

into this:

```
db.collection("suggest").add(userData2)
          .then(function() {
              console.log("Successfully written!");
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
              console.error("Error writing: ", error);
          });
```

`add()` method will generate a unique ID for each document.

> [`add`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference.html#add)
>
> `add(data: DocumentData): Promise<DocumentReference>`
>
> Add a new document to this collection with the specified data, assigning it a document ID automatically.

Comment: thank you response at the first. The method have a problem, the userid(ex"0001") maybe have more data(message) at different time. it will not to query the same user speak at after.

Comment: you can update the data later https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49150917/update-fields-in-nested-objects-in-firestore-documents/49151326#49151326 https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data

Comment: update the data ,it will same problem , is it overwrite before data? thanks.