# Write data in to nested object in firebase firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a data structure that looks as follows:
[image]

This is the top level of the collection:
[image]

I want to write to increment the field count but I can't do it. I've tried so many different methods that I'd rather not go through all of them. The closest I've gotten was through:

```
const pageRef = admin.firestore().collection("pages").doc(image.page);

pageRef.set(
  {
    [`images.${image.position}.count`]: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(
      1
    ),
  },
  { merge: true }
);
```

But that leaves me with:
[image]

Please help. Changing the structure of pages is an option.

This is what I've tried to replicate:
[Update fields in nested objects in firestore documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49150917/update-fields-in-nested-objects-in-firestore-documents)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is on how the point notaition is being used.

In the [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49150917/update-fields-in-nested-objects-in-firestore-documents) you shared the example they use is:

> ```
> var setAda = dbFirestore.collection('users').doc('alovelace').update({
>     "first.test": "12345"
> });
> ```

Applying this to your Code and model would be:

```
const pageRef = admin.firestore().collection("pages").doc(image.page);

pageRef.set(
  {
    `images[${image.position}].count`: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(
      1
    ),
  },
  { merge: true }
);
```

This will affect the element in the Array Images, the element `image.position` its value count.