# How to move a timestamp from one field to another in Firebase Firestore?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I have the following document structure called `activity`:

```js
{
  duration: {
    start?: Timestamp,
    end?: Timestamp
  }
}
```

If I want to copy `duration.end` into `duration.start` I do this:

```js
...
const activity = (await activityRef.get()).data()
const { duration } = activity;
duration.start = duration.end

await activityRef.update({
  duration
});
```

Problem is, now my `duration.start` is no longer a `timestamp` and instead a `seconds, nanoseconds` object:

```js
{
  duration: {
    start: {
      seconds: Number,
      nanoseconds: Number,
    },
    end: Timestamp
  }
}
```

How do I move a `timestamp` from one field to another without it losing its type?

Also is there a proper way to avoid having to deal with `seconds, nanoseconds` objects, without having to reinstantiate an `admin.firestore.Timestamp`?

Comment: Try updating the start value directly using dot notation instead of updating the entire duration field. It's likely the case that timestamp types are only preserved when they are the individual value being added, not when they are nested under some object you provide. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49150917/update-fields-in-nested-objects-in-firestore-documents

Comment: Did the comment above address your concern @akopyl? If so, please post it as an answer so that it woluld be helpful to other members with similar questions.